# Is there a daemon that can poll Prometheus targets and relay to Graphite?

Tags: proxy, daemon, prometheus, graphite

I am running a Graphite based collection, and have a couple of Prometheus only apps that I would like to be able to monitor through that.

Does anyone know of a proxy-like piece of software that can poll Prometheus targets, and relay that information into a Graphite based backend?

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus would be the piece of software you're looking for.

Specifically, have a look at its [remote_write](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#remote_write) configuration section which documents how it [supports Graphite](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/integrations/#remote-endpoints-and-storage).

Comment: The whole point was not having to run a Prometheus setup, but just as thin a client as possible that does nothing but poll and relay.

Comment: I though the whole point was having all metrics in Graphite. I'm not exactly sure what your resource contraints are but it would be relevant to make your question clearer as to the fact that you don't want to run Prometheus to do what you ask for as well as what limits you have to proposed solutions.

Comment: Unless i've misunderstood, Prometheus has its own poller built in, but Graphite needs data pushed.

What i'm looking for is a small daemon that can poll a Prometheus endpoint, and push it to Graphite, and yes, Prometheus itself might be able to do that but I am not looking to run two backends and two pollers (i'm already gathering data via LibreNMS)

Comment: You're looking for a solution to poll data from a Prometheus target to push into graphite, yet don't want to run 2 pollers. Avoiding Prometheus will save you one exactly one backend that won't be queried and hence won't consume much. Feel free to look around for a solution that you envision but I'm not sure it exists and if it does, what can of reliability and maintenance it has because it'll be a mostly niche solution IMO.